# Cleanly creating an object graph of domain objects using SimpleJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

For a new project, we've decided to use Spring MVC, and JdbcTemplate (specifically SimpleJdbcTemplate) for persisting domain objects. One issue I've been having with this approach is how to cleanly create object graphs from SELECT queries. The RowMapper mechanism seems to work great when I am pulling rows from a single table; I become concerned when I'm mapping the results of a JOIN query.

To give a concrete (yet entirely fabricated) example, suppose I have two entities in an N-to-1 relationship:

```
public class Invoice {
    private Customer customer;
    ...
}

public class Customer {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

I would like to be able to call a `selectInvoices()` method on my `InvoiceDAO`, and retrieve a list of `Invoice`'s populated with fully-formed `Customer` instances. Instead, I find myself tempted to do something like the following:

```
public class Invoice {
    // this makes me unhappy
    private int customerId;
    ...
}
```

What is the best practice for cleanly making this happen? Should I just bite the bullet and use an ORM?

Comment: Good question, and if you don't want to muddy your DAO's or POJO's then you will have to go the ORM route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what an ORM is good at. If you want to do it all by yourself, my trick is to use a map to hold the customers:

```
Map<Long, Customer> customersById = new HashMap<Long, Customer>();
...
public Invoice mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    Invoice invoice = ...
    // populate invoice fields
    Long customerId = rs.getLong("customerId");
    Customer c = customersById.get(customerId);
    if (c == null) {
        // first time we meet this customer
        c = ...
        // populate customer fields from result set
        customersById.put(customerId, c);
    }
    invoice.setCustomer(c);
}
```

Comment: I see how this mitigates (but doesn't eliminate) the N+1 SQL anti-pattern. It seems like a good solution if I know my "customers" are fairly few (or repetitive given typical inputs). It doesn't muddy my RowMapper with too much knowledge of the customer table; that knowledge stays kept in the CustomerDAO. Feels like a shame to be losing the performance and ACID properties of instructing the DB to do the join though. That's the nature of compromises, right?

Comment: The idea of the above code is precisely to load invoices with their customer from a single resultset, coming from a join query such as `select i.*, c.* from invoice i inner join customer c on i.customer_id = c.id where ...`. I don't see any N + 1 problem here.

Comment: Oh! I read your answer wrong. You're right: no N+1 problems there.